# Duplicate table value to have the same size

Tags: matlab

I have two tables of different size. I'm using Matlab, it doesn't matter I just need the logic of doing this

the first table contains 8 elements the second one contains 3

```
0.04     0.1
0.08     0.2
0.12     0.3
0.16
0.20
0.24
0.28
0.32
```

I want to compare the two tables, repeating same value in the second table while tab1(i) < tab2(i) in order to get two tables of the same size the result must be like this

```
0.04     0.1
0.08     0.1
0.12     0.2
0.16     0.2
0.20     0.2
0.24     0.3
0.28     0.3
0.32     0.0
```

i've tried this

```
for ii=1:sizex1(1)
    for jj=1:ssimagefile
        if x2imagefile(jj)<=z1(ii)
            tab2(ii)=z1(ii)
            fprintf(file, '%f %f \n', [ii tab2]');
            jj=jj+1;
        else
            ii=ii+1;
        end
    end
```

Comment: please provide codes which you have tried

Comment: @user3625507 please add this code to your question (you can edit your question), it is very difficult to read in the comments and it is an important part of the question anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Matlaby way to do it:

```
%// Add zeros to the end of tab2 so that it is as long as tab1
tab3(numel(tab1)) = 0;
%// use bsxfun to find for each number, which rows it will be replicated into
I = bsxfun(@le, tab1, tab2') & bsxfun(@gt, tab1, [-inf,tab2(1:end-1)']);
%// use find to convert the rows from the step before to indexes of where the numbers lie in tab1
[~,c] = find(I);
%// populate tab3 with the repeated numbers from tab2
tab3(1:numel(c)) = tab2(c);
```

And a simpler way using for loops:

```
tab3 = zeros(size(tab1));
for row = 1:numel(tab1)
    idx = tab2 > tab1(row);
    if any(idx)
        tab3(row) = min(tab2(idx));
    end
end
```

Comment: @user3625507 but don't use it unless you understand *WHY* it works

Comment: yes of course thank you, i have to understand it because i have to explain it in my internship report, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You could also take the following vectorized approach in case you prefer to avoid `bsxfun`:

```
tab2_sorted = sort(tab2);       % Sort tab2
tab3=zeros(size(tab1));         % Initialize the new table

% Fill the new table with the values of tab2
tab3(tab1<=tab2_sorted(3))=tab2_sorted(3);
tab3(tab1<=tab2_sorted(2))=tab2_sorted(2);
tab3(tab1<=tab2_sorted(1))=tab2_sorted(1);
```